# Jinja2 returns empty page

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 with python 3.3.1 and my templatecode is the following:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
  <p>Why, hello there!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my python.cgi file is the following :

```
from jinja2 import Template
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath="\\")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment( loader=templateLoader )
TEMPLATE_FILE = "cgi-bin/example1.jinja"
template = templateEnv.get_template( TEMPLATE_FILE )

templateVars = { "title" : "Test Example",
               "description" : "A simple inquiry of function." }
outputText = template.render( templateVars )
```

And all I am getting is a blank page with no html, the cgi-header is working meaning the browser is recognizing that its html but 'Why, hello there' is not being displayed. jinja2 is working too since in interpreter mode I created a simple template like :

```
t = Template("hello! {{title}}")
t.render(title="myname")
```

and it displayed hello! myname

Nothing wrong in the error_log either. Whats going on?

Comment: You cannot use a string with just a backslash; `"\"` is invalid Python. Presumably you simplified it, but then at least still keep the sample valid.

Comment: Did you **print** `outputText` or otherwise wrote the result to stdout?

Comment: im sorry I didnt understand the comment, did you mean on the third line of python.cgi the "\" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python interpreter auto-echoes the result of any expression as long as it is not returning `None`.

In a CGI script you need to explicitly write the result out:

```
outputText = template.render( templateVars )
print(outputText)
```

`template.render()` only produces the string result, it doesn't write this to stdout for you.